# Son's responsibility on fathers salat

Tags: salat, sunni, hanafi

According to the Shia school of thought, it's the sons responsibility to complete any salat which his father missed when the father passes away.

According to the Sunni school of thought, does the son have the same responsibility?

Comment: AFAIK: According to Shiism that responsibility is on the eldest son.

Answer (score 1):

We know that, for an actions are acceptable, [there should be intention behind it](http://www.40hadithnawawi.com/index.php/the-hadiths/hadith-1). You can perform salat for him, but you can not bring the intention that will make your prayers acceptable in his account.

Quran is very clear on this subject that [you can not bear someone else's burdon](http://quran.com/35/18), no matter how close you are.

> And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another. And if a heavily laden soul calls [another] to [carry some of] its load, nothing of it will be carried, even if he should be a close relative. (35:18)

Answer (score -1):

The son can offer Nawafil (optional) prayer for his father if he is dead but he cannot replace his Faraid (obligatory) prayers. The father has to make up the obligatory prayers himself and ask for forgiveness. Rest ALLAH (The Glorified) KNOWS BEST.